# Error: [Immer] An immer producer returned a new value *and* modified its draft. Either return a new value *or* modify the draft. redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I am making this shopping cart in redux-toolkit and rtk query. I want to change the cartItem index with product id.

I think the problem is with this line of code:

```
const cartItems = state.cartItems
```

My full code:

```
    import { createSlice, current } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
    
    const initialState = {
        cartItems: [],
    };
    
    export const cartSlice = createSlice({
        name: 'cartSlice',
        initialState: initialState,
        reducers: {
         
            setToCart: (state, action) => {
                const { payload:product, newQty = 1 } = action;
                const cartItems = state.cartItems;
                const quantity = cartItems?.[product?._id]
                    ? parseInt(cartItems[product._id].quantity + newQty)
                    : 1;
    
                cartItems[product._id] = {
                    ...product,
                    quantity,
                };
                return {
                    ...state,
                    cartItems: cartItems
                }
            },
        },
    });
    
    export const {setToCart} = cartSlice.actions;
    export default cartSlice.reducer;
```

Here is `action.payload`:

```
{
    img: "_OCT2HGtyHbioAuVTMGcA-mauntain.jpg",
    name: "iphone",
    price: 600001,
    _id: "60d375ed3224711bc0f3538a"*
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error states, when using an Immer-powered reducer you must *Either return a new value *or* modify the draft.*

You are modifying the `cartItems` array.  You do not need to return anything from your reducer.  Just modify the values that you want to change.  That's the magic of Redux Toolkit! (powered by Immer).

---

There are some other issues with your reducer:

- `action` will not have a property `newQty`.  It will only have a `type` and `payload`. Perhaps `newQty` is a property of the `payload`?
- It seems like `cartItems` is a dictionary keyed by `_id`, but you initialize it as an empty array `[]` instead of an empty object `{}`.
- `parseInt` doesn't make sense *outside* of an addition statement.  `parseInt("2" + "2")` will be `22`, not `4`.

A "fixed" version *might* look like this, depending on how you structure your payload:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
    cartItems: {},
};

export const cartSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'cartSlice',
    initialState: initialState,
    reducers: {
        setToCart: (state, action) => {
            const { payload } = action;
            const { product, newQty = 1 } = payload;
            const cartItems = state.cartItems;
            // If already in cart, increase quantity.
            if (cartItems[product._id]) {
                cartItems[product._id].quantity += newQty;
            }
            // Otherwise add to cart.
            else {
                cartItems[product._id] = {
                    ...product,
                    quantity: newQty
                }
            }
            // Don't return anything.
        },
    },
});

export const {setToCart} = cartSlice.actions;
export default cartSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: As you assume, It has only a type and payload. This is a great explanation. You have saved me a lot of time. Thank you for your support.